# Multiple databases in same MySQL server

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-mysql

I already have and database in MySQL for my one Django project.
I need to make two separate Django projects share the same database.

**project1/settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'read_default_file': '/etc/mysql/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

**project1/etc/mysql/my.cnf:**

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[client]
database = project1
user = project_user
password = Password
port = 3307
default-character-set = utf8
```

Here, can I have a different database (`database = project2`) for my second project?

I am willing to use same `user` and same `password`.

How can I do that?

Comment: use create database project2 and use that in your connect sring

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you. I can create new database project2 , but how my running project will know that, which database in used? if i go to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` from my project2 , it's show same thinks for project1 and project2.

Comment: every porject has its own my.cnf. where you declare `database ` , so after creatuing a new datqabase, inmyssql work bench or with mysql client  you edit the my.cnf file of your new proiject one project can also have multiple databases https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE DATABASE project2;
```

You can run the above query from MySQL client console. That will create new database "project2" in MySQL.

And change the value to "database = project2" in your second project's my.cnf. That should work. You just need to have a different my.cnf file for second project. First project path is "project1/etc/mysql/my.cnf" as mentioned above. You should have something similar "project2/etc/mysql/my.cnf" as second project my.cnf path.

Comment: well, if i go to `my.cnf` from my **project2** it's showing me `[client]
database = project1
user = project_user
password = Password
port = 3307` if i change here, does my project1 will able to insert data to project2?

Comment: I have updated the answer above to explain better. You need to have a different my.cnf file for second project. Each project should have a separate my.cnf file.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, now after changing `my.cnf` file for project2, if i open project1 in my visual code and run the project1, it's doesn't find the project1 database. So , if i want to run my both project in the same environment, how can i get both databases active?

Comment: You can have multiple databases/schemas in a MySQL instance. You can create both project1 & project2 databases in your MySQL.

Comment: I created project1 and project2 databases in MySQL instance. Now the problem i am facing , if i edit `my.cnf` file as the name of project2, unfortunately, it's also changed for project1 `my.cnf` file. What i am trying to say you that, i am getting same `my.cnf` file by going `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` this location from different project. I understand that, there should be different `my.cnf` file for different projects, but while i open my project in **vSCode** , if i go `my.cnf` file, both having same database.